# PostgreSQL Heroku Symfony2 File mapping

Tags: postgresql, symfony, heroku, doctrine-orm, mapping

I have load project Symfony2 with PostgreSQL
[**this my project**](http://desolate-journey-6777.herokuapp.com/app_dev.php/).
In my local host this project work not problem.
In heroku when I run:

heroku run php app/console doctrine:schema:create

[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
File mapping drivers must have a valid directory path, however the given path [/tmp/build_d2abd4d4e9172642941b867e70a389eb/src/App/FirstBundle/Resources/config/doctrine
] seems to be incorrect!

this is my config.yml:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        
        default:
            driver:   "%database_driver%"
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8


orm:

    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
```

and I use yml and xml file Resources/config/doctrine/.. for my Entity

and I repeat in my local host project work and I see table for my entity in phppgadmin.

This example in my local run app/console doctrine:schema:validate

[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.

[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

I try find response for my question in google but no result, help please

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your parameters.yml placed on heroku (not your local version)

If in this file you see db host - localhost, you are forget configure DB
You need visit - [Heroku addon stores](https://addons.heroku.com/#data-stores) and choose what type of DB you need. 
After that you have two ways,
first - edit parameters.yml.dist in git (realy bad idea - but fast for you)
second - learn incenteev-parameters from composer, how to define parameters in composer. For Russian lang - i found this [site](http://stfalcon.com/blog/post/deploying-symfony2-applications-on-heroku-cloud)

Did all entities is in git repo?

Let me know about results.

Comment: hello, I check this problem, I have old version some bundle doctrine and I run composer update, thats change composer.lock and deploy in heroku. Now all work.